# Adapting Error to Except

Tags: haskell, exception

Now that `Control.Monad.Error` is deprecated, and `Control.Monad.Except` reigns supreme, a lot of sources online haven't caught up, and still show examples of how to use `Error`.

So how would I go about turning

```
instance Error MyError where
  noMsg  = ...
  strMsg = ...
```

into something using `Except`. Just replacing `Error` with `Except` didn't work as `Except` expects additional type parameters

I understand that those exact methods don't exist in `Except`, so what's the alternative?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Short answer is: Replace `Error` by nothing at all, replace `ErrorT` by `ExceptT`, and things should continue to work as long as you don't use `Error`s methods, `fail` (which now has a different definition), or failing pattern matches in `do` notation.

The essential difference between the old `Control.Monad.Error` system and the new `Control.Monad.Except` system is that the new system imposes *no* class restriction on the error/exception type.

It was found that the ability to use any error/exception type at all, polymorphically, was more useful than the somewhat hacky ability to customize conversion of string error messages.

So the class `Error` has simply disappeared.

As a side effect, `fail` for `ExceptT` now is lifted from the underlying monad.  This also changes the effect of failing patterns in `do` notation.

The old definition was:

```
fail msg = ErrorT $ return (Left (strMsg msg))
```

which I think is equivalent to

```
fail msg = throwError (strMsg msg)
```

If you still need this behavior, you can instead use

```
throwError yourIntendedErrorValue
```

(`throwE` works instead if you're using `transformers` (i.e. `Control.Monad.Trans.Except`) rather than `mtl`.)

The old `do` pattern matching failure would apply to things like

```
do
    Just x <- myErrorTAction
    ...
```

when the action actually returns `Nothing`.  This is more awkward, but you could e.g. replace it with an explicit `case` match (essentially desugaring it):

```
do
    y <- myErrorTAction
    case y of
        Nothing -> throwE ...
        Just x -> do
           ...
```

@DanielWagner suggests the following to avoid extra indentation:

```
do
    x <- myErrorTAction >>= maybe (throwError ...) return
    ...
```

The removal of `Error` also eliminates the need for an inconsistency in naming that `Control.Monad.Error` had: Most transformers follow the rule that `SomethingT` is the name of the transformer, and `Something` is a type alias for `SomethingT ... Identity`.  The old `ErrorT` broke that because the `Error` class was used for something entirely different.

In the new system, `Except e = ExceptT e Identity`, like for other transformers.

Comment: you say `fail` works different now, could you provide an example of how it was, and how equivalent code would need to be written?

Comment: @ElectricCoffee I expanded that bit.

Comment: @ØrjanJohansen Another pattern I've used occasionally: `do { y <- myErrorTAction >>= maybe (throwError ...) return; ... }`. Avoids having to add an indentation level, and can be adapted to other pattern matches; e.g. `do { y_ <- myErrorTAction; y <- case y_ of { Nothing -> throwError ...; Just v -> return v }; ... }` which adds a layer of indentation but only temporarily (i.e. would not require nested indentation if you want to do two pattern matches).

Comment: @DanielWagner Thanks, added the first part.